How to format the numeric value of a cell in Excel using flutter?
I use the Excel library in Flutter Project, there are formatting template classes(NumFormat), but there is no currency formatting to display the ruble or dollar sign.
The library makes it possible to create your own value format, but it is not clear where and how to use it, because when you try to write your own format and insert it into the CellStyle, the entire Excel file and its styles break.
I tried to add a style to the numeric value of a cell:
sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString('E$rowIndex')).cellStyle = CellStyle(
      numberFormat: NumFormat.custom(formatCode: '#,##0 ₽'),
     );


I tried using another option:
sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByString('E$rowIndex')).cellStyle = CellStyle(
     numberFormat: CustomNumericNumFormat(formatCode: '# ##0,00 ₽'),
     );


But nothing helped

Can you try this 2 changes: first use a dollar sign just to check if its ₽ the problem and also use it as a raw string (r at the beginning) r'$#,##0.00', if it works try to replace dollar back with ₽

When I try to execute at least one option, the Excel file breaks when I launch it, it writes:
"There was an error with some of the content in the book "
Used the command NumFormat.custom(formatCode: r'$#,##0') in CellStyle()
